# Connect to a remote pc not working

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have created an RDS Server and I think I have configured everything including certificates (self signed for testing).

As I need to test this before handover, I have started testing and I could find something strange. I can RDP to any server when accessing RD web within the domain servers. I mean login to any domain server -> https://servernameorip/rdweb -> login with domain user -> connect to a remote pc -> enter server name, credentials and connect -> success.

But the same steps (https://servernameorip/rdweb -> login with domain user -> connect to a remote pc -> enter server name, credentials and connect) when doing from the internet throws me an error as shown below:

Have anyone experienced this kind of error.? Any support would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Oops!!! sorry. Missed to mention..

Your computer cant verify the identity of the RD Gateway....

Comment: Sounds like a certificate issue. This may well be due to an issue with using self-signed certificates. Add the self-signed certificate into the "Trusted Root Certificate Authority" try it again.

Comment: It is there and in personal store. but not working. Will a valid trusted cert will solve the issue..?

Comment: **EDIT** Is the cert installed on the target computer as well? I was just checking to make sure you did have the certs. Is there any chance you could post the ENTIRE error message to your original question as well?

Comment: Sure, but when I am at my office only.. sorry.. hopefully I could test this by monday and will post the result. Hoping to see you here on monday :)